# Time out issue in classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I am working on a classic ASP project where I am getting time out issue when populating the data from DB and Bind it in the UI. The following error we got:
**Script timeout
The maximum amount of time for a script tp execute was exceeded. You can change this limit by specifying new value for the property Server.Scripttimeout or by changing the value in IIS asministration tools**

To resolve the issue we tried to do the pagination but it went unsuccessful.
There are several forms on one page with individual names (i.e. `form1`, `form2`) . We have implemented `Recordset` pagination within one particular form.
Along with the pagination edit and delete options are also available for a particular record in record set. The problem what we are facing is when we try to edit the record the form values are not coming to the posted page.

I have mentioned the code snippet as below:

```vb
Function someFunction
  data1=""
  <form name="Xyz" method="post" action="edit.asp">
  s=s&"<script>function relsubmit() {alert(" & data1 &"); rjob.submit(); } </script>"
  'Pagination code display only 30 records per page
  Do While Not ( rss.Eof Or rss.AbsolutePage <> iPage )
    'some code
    If (Action="RELEdit") Then
      s=s&"" & drsel &""
      s=s&"
      s=s&"" & clean(rss.Fields(4).value) & ""
    Else
    End If
    datadr1=datadr1& rss.Fields(0).value & ","
    rss.MoveNext 
  loop
  If (Action="RELEdit") then
    s=s&"<input type=hidden name=data1 value=""" & datadr1 & "">"
    s=s&"<input type=hidden name=data2 value=""" &datadr2 & """><</form>"
  End If
End Function
```

We have tried to get the value in edit.asp page using `request.form("data1")` the values are coming empty also we tried alert in the `relsubmit()` function it is showing as empty.

Can you please help me why the form values are posted as null or empty.
Also, please advise me if we have any other approaches to track the time out.

Comment: It's really hard to tell without more details about the query and it's performance, but in my opinion you should dump the idea of retrieving to many records and try to present them to your users. Look into smart ways of filtering because it's commonly very unlikely for users to page beyond the 3rd page of results.

Comment: It all depends on what your database is and the methods you are using to retreive the data. Just saying *"I am working on a classic ASP project where I am getting time out issue when populating the data from DB and Bind it in the UI."* doesn't give us any of this important information, also you don't show any code. This encourages guess work and your likely not to get the answer you seek.

Comment: @Filburt It depends on what it is being used for,  is it a purchase order system is a public facing website etc. You can't pigeon hole every project with the same set of values.

Comment: Hi Lankymart, its a classic ASP with win 2005,MS SQL 2005 Db.. When we are extracting small recordset its working fine ,because of the increase in number of records its throwing time out.. We tried paginagation but we were unable to achieve as we were getting empty data as posted value.. I just edited my question.. As we were unable to fix we thought of checking for other alteranatives .. Pls suggest me if you have any idea or let me know if you ned more details

Comment: @PrashantP I can't provide you a fully fleshed out solution, but as a general pattern I used back when I did classic ASP was to retrieve only the record IDs from the big query, storing those into a session variable and passed the IDs for the actual page into a query fetching all the details. However from what you added to your question, your actual problem is rather handling form postback data than the query itself.

Comment: @PrashantP The timeout issue is likely poorly written queries or lack of proper indexing in your tables. Pagination through the `ADODB.Recordset` will not help as this still requires the full query then the pagination is applied. Your best bet is to look at improving your query performance, can you test your query in SQL Server Management Studio, what response times are you getting (anything more then a few seconds and there's your bottle neck)?

Comment: @PrashantP Tried to edit your question to format the code better, but your code doesn't make a lot of sense. This line `<form name="Xyz" method="post" action="edit.asp">` dosn't appear to be part of the ASP processing and so should be outside of `<%` `%>` ASP processing tags like this `%><form name="Xyz" method="post" action="edit.asp"><%`. Also your string's are not correctly concatenated  `s=s&"" & drsel &""` will fail as the string is not terminated properly `s = s & """" & drsel & """"`. Are you sure this is working code?

Comment: @Lankymart.. Yes it is the working code..Also I have checked the timings of the query in profiler and it is taking 20ms ..  I am just guessing that its happening while binding it to the UI .. Can time out happen while binding to UI?

Comment: I m not able to provide the full code as it is a security issue. The code has started with <% %> and I have provided the code snippet hiding sql details.

Comment: @Lankymart, what's wrong with `s = s & "" & drsel & ""`? The "" are just empty strings and superfulous but it won't fail.

Comment: @PrashantP, instead of using recordset paging you could use one of the several SQL paging techniques. Recordset paging is not as efficient.

Comment: @John Your right. Was reading it wrong the fact they are there in the first place is pointless. But the code will still fail due to the `<form>` html tag will it not?

Comment: @Lankymart, yes form tag is not right like that, and there's plenty of other weirdness in that code.

Answer (score 2):

Place this code at the top of the ASP page you are running.
The values are in seconds (300 = 60*5 = 5 minutes)
This will extend the script runtime to 5 minutes. You can set any value even hours

```
<%Server.ScriptTimeout=600%>
```

Comment: This scrip-let only address the time-out issue. It allows your code to run for as long a time as you set so it can process the report. I have written ASP code which run for over 1 hour to generate a report.

Comment: That's nothing to be proud of.

Comment: `Server.ScriptTimeout` and indexing reports (by optimizing the data) are completely different subjects, so I reiterate *"How is that going to improve performance?"* Answer it isn't it just let's the script run longer, which is not a solution in my book.

Comment: For your code try separating the processes. (1) First Populate the record-set, If your pagination fail, temporarily abandon and write the script to select just a few records (2) Add your edit button to the record-set line items. When edit button clicked populate the form with selected records. (3) When form submit button clicked it performs the edit operation on the record.

Comment: That would make for a more rounded answer.